# Why is it not recommended to microwave UK or Canadian bacon?

Tags: food-safety, microwave, bacon

Following this thread ([Is it possible to cook bacon without melting as much fat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/100702/is-it-possible-to-cook-bacon-without-melting-as-much-fat)), @Italian Philosopher mentions that this is not a good idea for UK or Canadian bacon.

I've noticed that most bacon I purchase in the UK says do not microwave, although I do occasionally nuke a few slices of back bacon for a short blast to get the water and phosphates out before frying.

Having eaten a few sandwiches in the past that the bacon has been microwaved, I'm still here to tell the tale. I assume the "don't microwave" advice is because the fat won't fry or render properly, but why is this OK for stateside pork?

Comment: nuking bacon gets phosphates out? how?

Comment: If you microwave in a sealed container, water and the "White slime" come out, which can be poured away, the bacon dried with some kitchen paper and then fried as normal. No white gunk in the frying pan to adulterate the oil.

Comment: @Greybeard what’s the evidence for the white hunk being phosphates rather than just proteiny liquid like you get with defrosted shrimp?

Comment: 1. It is not the best quality bacon. 2.https://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-6573635/Controversial-food-additive-used-bacon-makes-lazy.html 3. A number of documentaries have shown chicken and bacon designated for the UK market has added phosphate to retain water bulk. I'll check the packet next time I'm near the fridge, it will say for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are talking about bacon in these terms:

[image: bacon bacon bacon]

I believe it's because of the meat content difference. American bacon has a much higher fat-to-meat ratio and it's usually thinner, so when you microwave it the thin meat gets crispy (which is, arguably, a good thing in this case).

Canadian and UK bacon have much more meat, and if you microwave it the meat will dry out too much that both texture and flavour will be ruined.

Comment: My pack of back bacon (which is the last image) says "Do not microwave". I'll check the package instructions for pork belly (streaky) next time I shop.

Comment: @Greybeard so... does this not answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, @Luciano forgot to sign it off.